# continuity multiple WSASend() io compretion ports

Tags: c++, winsock, io-completion-ports

Using TCP in IO completion ports from a server, if I make two consecutive `WSASend` in the same socket, the first sends "ABC" and the second sends "DEF" then when I call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` it tells me that the first `WSASend` only sent "AB" then I call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` again and it tells me that the second `WSASend` sent "DEF", is the client going to recv "ABDEF"? or will the second `WSASend` fail because the first `WSASend` message was incomplete?

Comment: This should be impossible. A partial write should only occur when something fatal occurs, preventing the subsequent write from making any progress at all. Are you sure you didn't process the completions out of order? (While the operations must complete in the order they were started, there is no guarantee you will receive/process the completion indications in order.)

Comment: The example I made was just imaginary, so that I can understand how io completion ports works. Then if `WSASend` sends an incomplete message, it means that I should close the socket?

Comment: You could close the socket. You could also post another send and see what error you get. You can also wait for a receive to error if you have one pending.

Comment: In other words, you can treat it as an error condition.  Presumably you already check to see whether the operation returned an error code; whatever you do in that case, you can do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving party will not receive ABDEF because this implies violated integrity of the stream.

If you issue WSASend() on ABC and DEF (in that order) and you get completions for 2 bytes for ABC and 3 bytes for DEF, the receiving party could have received nothing, A, AB, ABC, ABCD, ABCDE, or ABCDEF. Quite likely though, they haven't received anything beyond AB.

When you a completion for WSASend() that indicates anything other than a full send, you should terminate the socket. closesocket() will indeed be the last thing you should do; before then you should drain all outstanding sends and receives (CancelIoEx(), shutdown() et al).